# What's the difference between raisedButton and Container with onTap() (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter

When we want to achieve a button, we can choose raisedButton in flutter lib, also can a Container with `onTap()` function. So what's the difference between the two and which one should we choose in different situation?

Answer (score 3):

Container function doesnot have onTap option, but you can achieve it by wrapping it in **Guesture detector** or **Inkwell**. There are no changes in the backend. But Raised button gives you the elevation, and animation on tap. You can also do it in the container, but it requires you to manually do it.

If you want a simple button quickly use RaisedButton.
If you want a more complex one, use Container or mixture of Containers, RaisedButton etc.

Answer (score 3):

I am gonna offer something different... A tale of a treasure that is known to have answers to many questions, use cases and sometimes even examples. The name of this treasure is: official documentation. ;)

[RaisedButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html)

> A raised button is based on a Material widget whose Material.elevation increases when the button is pressed. Use raised buttons to add dimension to otherwise mostly flat layouts, e.g. in long busy lists of content, or in wide spaces. Avoid using raised buttons on already-raised content such as dialogs or cards.

[Container](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html)

> A convenience widget that combines common painting, positioning, and
> sizing widgets.

[GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)

> A widget that detects gestures. Attempts to recognize gestures that
> correspond to its non-null callbacks. If this widget has a child, it
> defers to that child for its sizing behavior. If it does not have a
> child, it grows to fit the parent instead. By default a
> GestureDetector with an invisible child ignores touches; this behavior
> can be controlled with behavior. GestureDetector also listens for
> accessibility events and maps them to the callbacks. To ignore
> accessibility events, set excludeFromSemantics to true. See
> flutter.dev/gestures/ for additional information. Material design
> applications typically react to touches with ink splash effects. The
> InkWell class implements this effect and can be used in place of a
> GestureDetector for handling taps.

[InkWell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html)

> A rectangular area of a Material that responds to touch. For a variant
> of this widget that does not clip splashes, see InkResponse... The
> InkWell widget must have a Material widget as an ancestor. The
> Material widget is where the ink reactions are actually painted. This
> matches the material design premise wherein the Material is what is
> actually reacting to touches by spreading ink.

Answer (score 1):

Well, technically you are right, they can both react to a click event. But a `RaisedButton` will have all the styles specific to the target platform taken care of for you (it inherits from `MaterialButton`).

note that it's the same in html: you can use a regular `div` with a click handler or use a button tag. The button will have a few styles already taken care of for you...